# Spectrum of the product of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $F$.

> Let $A,B\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+:=\left\{T\in \mathcal{B}(F);\,\langle Tx, x\rangle\geq 0,\;\forall\;x\in F\;\right\}$, be such that $AB\neq 0$. I want to show that 
>   $$\sigma(AB)\neq\{0\}\;.$$

Comment: For an element $T\in B(F)$, $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$ iff $T=0$, this is because the identity function on $\{0\}$ is the zero function.

Comment: I think it is true iff  T is positive

Comment: If $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$, then, sure, $T$ is positive.

Comment: Gould you please explain me why?

Comment: Because $T$ is positive iff $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb R_{\geq0}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that $\sigma(ST) \cup \{0\} = \sigma(TS) \cup \{0\}$. So if $A$ and $B$ are positive then, except possibly for the point $0$, $\sigma(AB)$ equals $\sigma(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})$. If $AB \neq 0$ then the latter is a nonzero positive operator, and hence it has a nonzero element in its spectrum. Therefore so does $AB$.

Comment: Could you explain why $AB \not= 0$ implies $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2} \not= 0$? I assume it has something to do with the positive semi-definiteness of $B$, since this is not correct if $B$ is merely self-adjoint.

Comment: Sure. We have $(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})^* = A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$. So $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2} = 0$ implies $A^{1/2}B^{1/2} = 0$ implies (multiplying by $A^{1/2}$ on the left and $B^{1/2}$ on the right) $AB = 0$.

Comment: That makes things clearer for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Incidentally, this argument also shows that $\sigma(AB)$ is contained in $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @NikWeaver According to you answer I think that if $A$ and $B$ are positive then $\sigma(AB)\subset\mathbb{R}_{+}$. However if in addition $AB\neq0$, then $\sigma(AB)\subset ]0,\infty[$. Do you agree with me? Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler: No, for instance, if $AB$ has a nontrivial kernel then $0$ will be in its spectrum.